# how put worksheet of spreadsheet into variable php?

Tags: php, api, google-drive-api, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet document in Google Drive, I want put this content in a variable php to get the value of cells, what is the API that I should use? More links into the documentation are invalids. 
I need to authenticate with a google account login when the user tries to access the file.

I follow this api but I don't know itself is deprecated or not : https://github.com/asimlqt/php-google-spreadsheet-client

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

The Google Spreadsheets API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/) is the most complete way of accessing the data within a spreadsheet. Official support for PHP is provided as part of the [Zend framework](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.gdata.spreadsheets.html), although the 3rd party library you linked to may work.

Alternatively you can use the [Google Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/manage-downloads#downloading_google_documents) to download the spreadsheet in another file format.